# Android ListView SectionIndexer

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter, fastscroll

I have no problem using section indexer normally but here is what I am trying to do:

I have an alphabetical list that uses headers and entries - they all work perfect.  However I want to add custom list items above the A section.  I can do this no problem, however I don't want the section indexer overlay showing up when I am on those items.  How can I tell the section indexer not to display its overlay (still keep the fast scroll bar on the side) when above those section.

Note that the areas must be registered with the sections array or the fast scroll bar will not align perfectly.  Thus I just need a way to tell the overlay to display, or not to display.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something similar to contact list. Just in case a rubbish idea what if you add the items above section A as list header in a linear layout not sure if it would work just a try out.